# Draw many lines with Performance

Tags: ios, drawing

Hey i need a help with building an app. I build an art app, this app is working with interferencies. Thats the reason i need to draw many lines in this app. More lines are better for the interefernces. I think the problem is the iPad can't handle too many lines, because the speed or the performance is too slow.
I don't know how can i speed up my code for more performance on the iPad. Should i use Open GL or something else...

What can i do?

Here are the Draw.m

```
#import "Draw.h"

@implementation Draw


- (IBAction) sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", slider.value];
    //NSLog(@"slider value = %f", sender.value);
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}




- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    //NSLog(@"slider value = %f", self.bounds.size.width);

    CGMutablePathRef cgpath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(cgpath, NULL, 0, 500);


    CGMutablePathRef cgpath2 = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(cgpath2, NULL, 0, 500);

    UIBezierPath *uipath = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
    [uipath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];

    int step = 5;
    int iterations = self.bounds.size.width/step;

    for (int i = 0; i < iterations+1; i++){
    //CGPathAddCurveToPoint(cgpath, NULL, 1+i, 0, 1+i, 0, 1+i ,0);

        CGPathAddLineToPoint ( cgpath,  NULL, 0, 0 );
        CGPathAddLineToPoint ( cgpath,  NULL, 0, 768 );
        CGPathAddLineToPoint ( cgpath,  NULL, step*i-slider.value*2, 768 );
        CGPathAddLineToPoint ( cgpath,  NULL, step*i, 0 );
        CGPathAddLineToPoint ( cgpath,  NULL, (step*i)+step, 0 );

    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, cgpath);

    [self strokeUIBezierPath:uipath];

    CGPathRelease(cgpath);
}

- (void)strokeContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}

- (void)strokeUIBezierPath:(UIBezierPath*)path
{
    [path stroke];
}

@end
```

[image http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/375/53178410200339197475308.jpg](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/375/53178410200339197475308.jpg)

Comment: Can you please post one or two pictures (with different slider values) of what you are trying to draw? That would help figure out better ways to draw it.

Comment: Also, your code seems to be incorrect. You are never calling `strokeContext(context)` so the CGPath is never stroked. You are however calling `strokeUIBezierPath:` with the Bezier path that has no lines in it, you never modify it.

Comment: Here a Screenshot from the Simulator http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/375/53178410200339197475308.jpg
The slider controls at the moment the interferncies...

The code is at the moment experimental, but i think this is not the main problem...

Answer (score 2):

the problem with bezier paths is, that they can be quite 'calculation heavy'.

You could either use straight lines (   `CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);`)

Or you use graphics acceleration.
You could either dive directly into OpenGL or use a game engine to help you with some of the code.

One of the most popular ones ( and as I think quite easy to use ) is cocos2d.

Comment: I read something about UIBezierPath it seems faster then CGContext, but in the next step i should experiment with OpenGL

Comment: you think opengl is better for that?

Comment: looking at the image you posted i would suggest drawing everything into an image and then display the image, if that is possible.. you can also scale the image if needed.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have sample code for this, since I am still not really sure, what is supposed to happen! You can use similar code like you have above and just exchange the CGContextRef to an image drawing context UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myView.bounds.size);
//your drawing code here...
image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();   and now you have an image, that you can scale using the transform property of an imageview

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting better performance using a pattern to fill the screen. There is an entire section with sample code in [the Quartz Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_patterns/dq_patterns.html).

In your case you could create a very small pattern cell (height = 1) with just one black pixel to the very left followed by the same number of white pixels as the distance to the next line.